# .NET Standard project build fails with unhelpful message

Tags: .net, xamarin, asp.net-core, xamarin.android, .net-standard

When trying to build a project targeting .NET Standard 1.3 (a class library to be used by a Xamarin application), I get the following message and a failing build:

> Error : Your project is not referencing the ".NETPlatform,Version=v5.0" 
>   framework. Add a reference to ".NETPlatform,Version=v5.0" in the 
>   "frameworks" section of your project.json, and then re-run NuGet restore.

The `project.json` looks like this (I haven't edited it, this is what was originally generated for me):

```
{
  "supports": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1",
    "NJsonSchema": "6.5.6190.16910"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.3": {}
  }
}
```

There is no information online as to how I would add the reference it says to add, and the values it gives do not work as is.

How do I get this project to build?

Update:

Tried this https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/12918 and the error output has updated to

```
Error : Your project is not referencing the     
".NETStandard,Version=v1.3" framework. Add a reference to 
".NETStandard,Version=v1.3" in the "frameworks" section of your 
project.json, and then re-run NuGet restore.
```

Update:

I've gotten it to the point that it tries to build another project in the solution, and gives thousands of errors along the lines of

> System.Object is not defined or imported

Comment: are you building a library? or something that should run on a phone. Netstandard is for class libraries only.

Comment: A portable class library

Comment: Also I have .NET Core installed on the build machine

Comment: Have you tried changing the version of `NetStandard.Library` to `1.5.0-rc2-24027`? I'm pretty sure that 1.6.0 doesn't support netstandard1.3.

Comment: 1.5.0-rc2 didn't help, getting System.Object not defined

Comment: Do you build from visual studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the release of VS 2017, I've upgraded my project to .NET Standard using the new csproj style. It appears that .NET dropped the project.json, so I'm closing this question.